# How to extract storage account name and blob name from storage uri

Tags: c#, azure

I have below  url for azure 
https://restoreprojectdb.blob.core.windows.net/bacpacfiles/TestDB.bacpac

I want to extract "restoreprojectdb" and  "bacpacfiles" from the url using regex.

what is the best regex for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best regex, but if the format is always more or less the same I would just do `https:\/\/(.*)?.blob.core.windows.net\/(.*)?\/`

Answer (score 0):

```
https://(?<account>[a-z0-9]{3,24}).blob.core.windows.net/(?<container>[a-z0-9\-]{3,63})/
```

Minds naming rules: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2014/06/12/azure-storage-naming-rules/

Answer (score 0):

Use [BlobUriBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.bloburibuilder?view=azure-dotnet) to do something like:

```
return new BlobUriBuilder(uri).AccountName;
```

> The BlobUriBuilder class provides a convenient way to modify the contents of a Uri instance to point to different Azure Storage resources like an account, container, or blob.